# wgpu-native performance vs Vulkan

Tags: rust, game-development, vulkan, webgpu

I've been reading about wgpu-rs and that it uses Vulkan, Dx12, Metal etc if used to build native desktop applications. Given this could one expect comparable performance between wgpu-rs and using vulkan directly? I'm an amateur in the graphics programming space but have been working on a game in rust and the idea of being able to build to wasm once that is supported in wgpu-rs is very appealing.